# XPath to element text

Tags: xpath

```
<p><span class="label">key</span>value</p>
```

How am I able to get just the "value" out using xPath? I managed to get to the element using the following expression:

`//span[@class='label']/..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use <kbd>text()</kbd> to get the text from the `p`

```
//span[@class='label']/../text()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this one to get required value:

```
//p[span[@class='label']]/text()
```